# When using perforce how can you see the file history across all branches?

Tags: perforce

If I use the perforce command filelog it appears to show only the history for the current branch. Is there a way to see the history for all the branches?

EDIT:

the file name looks something like:

//depot/v2/top/foo.c
//depot/v1/top/foo.c

I want to see the history for v1 & v2. Is that a branch?

Comment: Use a wildcard that matches the files in all branches. The specific syntax depends on how you set up your branches.

Comment: Also depends whether you've ever renamed it...

Comment: I'm new to perforce. I'm beginning to think I'm might be confused about what a branch is.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `-i` or `-h` flags, the history will switch to another branch at branch or copy points respectively, but it will still be linear (just a more curvy line).

If you want a full graph, the best bet is the Revision Graph graphical tool:

https://www.perforce.com/video-tutorials/using-revision-graph

Comment: Revision Graph for the win! Best tool in the Perforce toolkit.

Comment: the -i didn't quite do what I wanted. I think what I want is the text version of the revision graph.

Comment: Could run Revision Graph, take a screenshot, and run it through http://picascii.com/?  

You could also script something that runs "filelog" recursively -- I used to have something like that to scrape data to feed into other tools, but the result isn't very human-readable since you can't really follow all the history between branches in one dimension.